# What's the best way to make a pdf book cover for Create Space?

Tags: print-design, inkscape, dpi, ppi

I downloaded a paper back book cover template from [Create Space](https://www.createspace.com/) and loaded it up into `Inkscape` (and used GIMP to crop the background images to fit the template).

What steps should I take, and what settings should I use, to guarantee the final `pdf` file of the book cover will test out at **300 dots per inch** in **Adobe Acrobat XI preflight**?

1. Scenario One. Your background image jpegs have a resolution of 300 x 300 pixels.
2. Scenario Two. Your background image jpegs have a resolution of 72 x 72 pixels.

Comment: Related question: [Vectors or 300 dpi TIFFs for printing?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17152/8708)

Answer (score 1):

The image dimensions are how you calculate what size they need to be placed into your Inkscape file to keep a 300dpi PDF.

For the 300px file, it would need to be placed in your PDF at 1" square (300px/inch).

The 72 pixel one would have to be placed in your PDF at approximately .25" square (4 x 72 = roughly 300).

You could, of course, scale them larger in your Inkscape file, but the larger you go, the less pixels-per-inch you'll have when you print (increasing the likelihood of it becoming pixelated).

Comment: Sounds like you know what you are doing. But your suggestions are too brief. Do you have time to write a tutorial? Also, I use GIMP to crop the background images to fit the template (often 2232 pixels wide by 2907 pixels tall). Can I scale a 72 x 72 ppi image up to 300 x 300 ppi in  GIMP? How would I do that? Also, don't forget, if you export a bitmap in Inkscape at 300 dpi, the size of the image goes way up! What to do?

Comment: @AlanDrabke: all of your questions have been covered here before. Search the tag "dpi": ( http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dpi )

Comment: @AlanDrabke I think you are maybe confusing some concepts. Do do what horatio suggests and read up a bit on Pixel dimensions vs. DPI. Then maybe come back and add a few more details to your question and we can try and be more specific.